# How to model a star shaped fruit?

Tags: modeling

I already tested with Extra-Simple star but that's not what I'm expecting to get.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: hello, what part are you struggling with? the fruit itself? the shell? both? Also maybe show a front view (or side view)?

Answer (score 9):

You can create a profile with a *Mirror* modifier, shift it from its origin:

[image]

Give it an *Array* modifier, deactivate *Relative Offset*, activate *Object Offset* mode, with an empty as *Object* that is placed at its origin. Rotate the empty 72° on the Z axis:

[image]

Begin to extrude up the profile, you can even mirror on the Z axis if the shape is symmetrical on Z:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @moonboots for this tutorial..I have a clear picture on howto make it. gracias!